# Regular expression for SSN number

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where the system will not allow the following patterns within the SSN.

- All identical: XXXXXXXXX
- Ascending sequential: X, X+1, X+2, etc., to X+8
- Descending sequential: X, X-1, X-2, etc., to X-8
- Repeating patterns, where X, Y, & Z are identical numbers:

  ```
  XYZXYZXYZ 
  XXXYYYZZZ 
  XYXYXYXYX 
  XYXYXYXYY 
  XYXYXYXYZ
  ```

This is not the 9 digit related regular expression. It's a 9 digit format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSN Regex for 123-45-6789 OR XXX-XX-XXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087468/ssn-regex-for-123-45-6789-or-xxx-xx-xxxx)

Comment: @Shekhar , it is not a dupe of *that* post

Comment: Please do not add "ASAP" to any questions here - remember that queries are answered by **volunteers**.

Answer (score 0):

This one will find `XXXXXXXX` and repeating sub patterns

```
^(?=\d{9})(?:(\d{1,8})\1*|(\d\d)\2*\d|((\d)+\g{-1}{2}){3})$
```

or

```
^(?=\d{9})(?:(\d{1,8})\1*|(\d\d)\2*\d|(\d)+\3\3(\d)\4\4(\d)\5\5)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ2pC2/3)

**For the ascending or descending ones:**

Regex is the wrong tool for such a task!
Regex is only useable for regular languages and comparing numbers is clearly not regular, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640192/regular-expressions-matching-if-number-is-greater-then)

You have to do the increment / decrement check manually with the programming language you are using.
If you want to use regex for that you have to hardcode each number.

Comment: Thank you fabian... can any one please respond to that query.. I want to check for increment / decrement values as well.

Comment: Hi Fabian, could you please post with out \g which is working earlier for us. It is not working with \g in our code.